# Matplot histogram of Pytorch Tensor

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor of size `10`, with only `1` values: `0` and `1`.

I want to plot an histogram of the tensor above, simply using `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`. This is my code:

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = torch.tensor([0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
print(t)
plt.hist(t, bins=2)
plt.show()
```

And the output:

[image]

Why are there so many values in the histogram? Where did the rest of the values come from? How can I plot a correct histogram for my tensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `plt.hist(t, bins=2)` function is not meant to work with tensors. For this to work properly, you can try using `t.numpy()` or `t.tolist()` instead. As far as I could educate myself, the way to compute a histogramwith pytorch is through the `torch.histc()` function and to plot the histogram you use `plt.bar()` function as follows:

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = torch.tensor([0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
hist = torch.histc(t, bins = 2, min = 0, max = 1)

bins = 2
x = range(bins)
plt.bar(x, hist, align='center')
plt.xlabel('Bins')
```

Some sources for plotting a histogram can be seen [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-compute-the-histogram-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compute-the-histogram-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch/) . I could not find the root cause for this and if some could educate me it will be great, but as far as I am aware, this is the way to plot a tensor

I changed the tensor to have 4 '1.0' and 6 '0.0' to be able to see the difference

Comment: "is not meant to work with tensors" - what's the difference, though? How is a 1D tensor different from a 1D NumPy array? _So_ different, in fact, that `plt.hist` produces nonsense (?) for the tensor? `numpy.histogram` works fine with this tensor...

Comment: I could not find any explanation to this phenomenon elsewhere, but as far as I could find, one can not simplt use the `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` function on a tensor directly. I added some sources in the answer